# How to list attributes that you defined in google protocol buffers?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, argparse, introspection

I have a google protocol buffer definition that looks something like the followwing:

```
message Foo {
   required string Name = 1;
   optional string Address = 2;
   optional string NickName = 3;
   optional  int32  height = 4;
}
```

Now in python, I'd like to list all the the attributes above, but only those attributes.  However, interactive python, I see that there's a whole lot more fields that are defined by google.  So this seems problematic.

I've looked at some of the stackoverflow posts on introspection.  There's an inspect module that looks nice, but the problem is the other members that google protocol buffers defines for me.

Is there a way to do so?

Here's what I'd like to do.  I have a python utility that fills out the above fields from the command line.  I use argparse, and I will:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.add_argument( "--attribute_name", blah)
```

I would like to place add_argument() in a loop and make it dynamic based off the proto file definition.  Basically, I don't want to keep modifying the utility's code, everytime I change the proto file.  It seems like I should be able to do this in python.  I just don't know how.

Anyone have a suggestion?

thanks.

For additional information, I took the above example, and compiled it with  protoc.  Here's the interactive output:

```
>>> import hello_pb2
>>> h = hello_pb2.Foo()
>>> dir(h)
['ADDRESS_FIELD_NUMBER', 'Address', 'ByteSize', 'Clear', 'ClearExtension', 'ClearField', 'CopyFrom', 'DESCRIPTOR', 'FindInitializationErrors', 'FromString', 'HEIGHT_FIELD_NUMBER', 'HasExtension', 'HasField', 'IsInitialized', 'ListFields', 'MergeFrom', 'MergeFromString', 'NAME_FIELD_NUMBER', 'NICKNAME_FIELD_NUMBER', 'Name', 'NickName', 'ParseFromString', 'RegisterExtension', 'SerializePartialToString', 'SerializeToString', 'SetInParent', '_InternalParse', '_InternalSerialize', '_Modified', '_SetListener', '__class__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', '_cached_byte_size', '_cached_byte_size_dirty', '_decoders_by_tag', '_extensions_by_name', '_extensions_by_number', '_fields', '_is_present_in_parent', '_listener', '_listener_for_children', 'height']
```

I inpected some promising fields like _fields, but that was empty.

**Here is the answer:**  (given by Kenton Varda's reply)

```
import hello_pb2
h = hello_pb2.Foo()
f = hello_pb2.Foo()
f.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name.keys()
```

Comment: You could eliminate all the attributes that start with '_', and all that are functions.  These will all be defined by the class, not  parameters.  That probably leaves you with the user defined fields, plus a few standards.  The standards will be the same across different user definitions.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  This is good approach too, but I wanted just the fields that I had defined.  It's a good back up plan tho.

Comment: What's your protoc version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to iterate over `Foo.DESCRIPTOR.fields`. See the `Descriptor` class:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.Descriptor-class

Every message class has a static member `DESCRIPTOR` which is the descriptor for that type.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Thanks!  How did you find it so fast?

Comment: I wrote most of Google's open source protobuf code. :)

Comment: Well thanks for that bit of technology.  We are using it at my company extensively right now.

Comment: I can directly see all the attributes by `dir()` a Message with protobuf 2.x. Is this a issue of protobuf 3.x?

Comment: Have the same question with @nn0p in python3 I can not see any fields with `dir()` , wondering how to make `dir()` work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a protobuf object to a dictionary:

```
import hello_pb2

def proto2dict(msg):
    hsh_val = dict(msg.ListFields())
    d = dict((k, hsh_val[hsh]) for k, hsh in msg.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name.items())
    return d

data = {"Name":"name", "Address":"address", "NickName":"nick", "height": 6}
msg = hello_pb2.Foo(**data)

assert proto2dict(msg) == data
```

Note: looks inefficient and may not work for nested definitions.

Answer (score 0):

On proto3 I couldn't make @Kenton Varda answer work.

This work for me:

```
from hello_pb2 import Foo

Foo.DESCRIPTOR.values_by_name
```